# Why Blender change the number of vertices when exporting .STL file

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, export, import, makehuman

I am working on Blender and MakeHuman. I import on blender a `*.mhx` file generated by MakeHuman. I take the file and I change the pose of the human (from stand to walk, bend, etc) after that I export the file as.STL. I remark that the number of vertices changed from pose to an another. I am wondering that changing the pose will allow just the modification of some vertices coordinates. So, Why the number of vertices changed. I think that blender redo the triangulation  each time when I export a file as .STL? any comments and how to resolve this problem

[make human file .mhx](http://www.megafileupload.com/mpfF/model.mhx)

[File imported to Blender](http://www.megafileupload.com/mpfD/111.stl)

[File : pose changed](http://www.megafileupload.com/mpfE/112.stl)

here the vertex number have been changed

Comment: While exporting to STL, overlapping vertices are merged. Could be your case? If not, could you provide pictures of the two poses?

Comment: @Carlo, I edited my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems to me that both STL have the same number of vertices (14444, in both Blender and MeshLab). How do you count them?

Comment: @Carlo, I am using Mathematica Import[*.stl,"VertexData"]. 111.stl have 86211 vertices and 112.stl have 86215 vertices. However, they are the same polygon number 28796.

Comment: If I import the objects with automatic merging disabling I can get a total of 86388 vertices for each object. Try to scale your object 100 times before exporting it and see if something change. My guess would be that Mathematica is running some kind of automatic merge

Comment: @Carlo, Yes, When I scale the model 10 times of the same model, the vertices number increases!